# No Wayland available on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, wayland

I just upgraded from ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10. Ubuntu 17.10 doesn't give me the option to log in under Wayland (it's not available). Here are the options i have available:
[image: options]

I am running this under hyper-v (not that i think that should matter). I've sen related post and tried solutions listed but nothing has worked like switching from gdm to lightdm & then back to gdm again. Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: Do you have Nvidia?

Comment: @pomsky Nope i'm using the default intel video ( HD4000) that comes on the I7-3770 processor.

Comment: Are you using a real machine or a Virtual Machine?

Comment: @Rolf a Virtual machine.

Comment: @coding4fun Try to change the type of virtual video card interface for the VM.  An example: if you would use Libvirt + QEMU + KVM to create virtual machines then the "--video qxl" is the only virtual video card interface that supports Wayland/Gnome. All the other video card interfaces (--video vga/cirrus/vmvga) do not work with Wayland; all fallback to Unity/X.org/LightDM.

Comment: I tried also, no solution so far  than to run xorg. If you want more than 800x600 resolution, makes sure the hyperv_fb module is loaded and that it is set as video in the grub defaults (there are plenty guides). VM must not have a RemoteFX card confgured